# IdentityDbContext how to run migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am new to Entity-Framework-5 and IdentityDbContext, I have managed to create my and create the AspNet membership tables,then i changed the type in one of the properties of the model, now my project wont run and its telling me that I need to run migrations. My question is, how to run migrations on the IdentityDbContext?
I cant find any good guides on how to do it.

`Additional information: The model backing the 'ApplicationIdentityUserDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).`

`public class ApplicationIdentityUserDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserProfile>
    {
        public ApplicationIdentityUserDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        { }
    }`
[image]
I have attached the error when I run enable-migrations.

Comment: running that show what dbContext I have, when I try to add a migration using configtypename, I get an error telling me that I cannot run migration on the specified dbConext

Comment: `oes not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Migrations configuration types must extend from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.`

Comment: You need to add migration for DBContext and not IdentityContext class. try this

Comment: When I tried that, I got an error saying that the migartions is already enabled, and did not try the -force option as I was unsure of the changes it would have on my aspnet membership.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do it by using the **enable-migrations** and **add-migration** command in the *Package Manager Console*
See [Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

This will generate migration files which you can apply to the database using the **update-database** command (or they run automatically depending on settings).

Make sure to select the correct *Default Project* in the *Package Manager Console*, it should be the project containing your context.

Comment: I have two DBConext, one normal, and the other one I can run migration normaly, I cant add-migration an the IdentityContext class.

Comment: I ended up using the -force option to solve my problem, thanks, I marked the answer as correct as I used the same methodology to solve it.

Comment: I had similar issues with dotnet core 2.2 and it was due to misconfiguration in the Startup.cs class and the settings json file having a bad connection string.