# IdentityDbContext how to configure migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Very similar to [IdentityDbContext how to run migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776586/identitydbcontext-how-to-run-migrations), but nothing there seemed to solve my issues. I've done my research, and there doesn't seem to be much info out there on using `IdentityDbContext` with migrations.

Some background... I inherited a web app that uses Entity Framework (which I'm not really that familiar with). I wasn't sure what libraries the packages.config was missing. I eventually got that sorted and found it used Entity Framework. I currently have it set to use 6.2.0 and the app seems to work fine.

The original developer had implemented `IdentityDbContext` and was using automatic migrations. He also had a `DbMigrationsConfiguration` implementation already defined, which I've added some seed queries to.

I've been using the automatic migrations so far, but I know it's not recommended for production. And I've had a couple times where I had to enable data loss to get the app to deploy, so that's probably why I shouldn't be using it.

This led me to [Code First Migrations with an existing database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database), specifically to set up migrations for an existing schema. That's where I'm lost. It doesn't seem like any of those instructions work for `IdentityDbContext`. Here's what I've tried:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'WebApp'.

PM> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName DataLayer
No context type was found in the assembly 'DataLayer'.
```

So, this led me to questioning whether `IdentityDbContext` would even work. So, next I tried changing my context to inherit from `DbContext`, which also meant having to add `DbSet` properties for users and roles so that my code would compile (though I never tested to see whether the app still worked). Now, here's what I tried:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName DataLayer
Migrations have already been enabled in project 'DataLayer'. To overwrite 
the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter.

PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges -ProjectName DataLayer
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'DataLayer'. (In 
Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager 
Console to add a migrations configuration).
```

**Am I reading this right? It can find a migrations configuration, but then it can't? Does anyone test these tools?**

Ok, so then I decide to take the recommendation of using -Force:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName DataLayer -Force
Code First Migrations enabled for project DataLayer.

PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges -ProjectName DataLayer
The project 'WebApp' failed to build.
```

And, as it says, the project failed to build because my existing `DbMigrationsConfiguration` implementation got overwritten. My existing implementation had a constructor that took some data for the seed queries. So, just for testing I decided not to worry about those seed queries, so I kept the auto-generated configuration and updated my app code to compensate. Now on to creating the initial migration:

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges -ProjectName DataLayer
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system 
cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

So, I already had `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1` installed to `DataLayer` through NuGet, but apparently it wasn't added as a reference in the `DataLayer` project. Added it in and let's try yet again:

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges -ProjectName DataLayer
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more 
validation errors were detected during model generation:

DataLayer.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key 
defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
DataLayer.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key 
defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on 
type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on 
type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

I assume these errors have to do with me switching `IdentityDbContext` to `DbContext`.

I don't really know where to go from here and I'm kind of frustrated. It really doesn't seem like this is going to work. If I really do have to change my `IdentityDbContext` over to a `DbContext` every time I add a migration, that's just unacceptable.

Even if I did get this to work, it seems convoluted when it's easy to write straight SQL DDL scripts. I suppose the advantage is migrations cover multiple versions of upgrades, but that can be handled with DDL scripts and a version number table, so that's not really an issue either.

**Should I just try to give up using migrations? Or maybe Entity Framework completely?**

**Edit:**

I found [No context type was found in the assembly EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900772/no-context-type-was-found-in-the-assembly-ef6) which explained why IdentityDbContext wasn't working. Apparently Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core doesn't get added as a reference, which seemed odd because I was kind of expecting the reference to be added with NuGet. But, that only solves the Enable-Migrations issue. Still has the no migration configuration error on Add-Migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I have it all fixed. So, on top of the Enable-Migrations tool apparently swallowing missing references instead of telling you about them, the Add-Migration tool apparently needs -ConfigurationTypeName in order to find the configuration. Not entirely sure why, since Enable-Migrations was able to find the configuration without this. But as long as it works, that's all I care about.